# FOS user for symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I'm new using symfony, and I have to use symfony 4 AND fos user bundle but I can't install it using composer ( since it's not officially supported ) , and I'm wondering how to bypass this. Can you explain me how to do it ?

Comment: It looks Symfony 4 is not supported by FoS User yet. You have to wait or try to use development versions.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/2639

Comment: Alright, I'll try to use the dev versions, thanks !

Comment: @Katk, Can you show whats your error?

Comment: I cannot, but composee just didnt' want to install it. ( Something like it didn't fit my minimal requirement ). All I had to do was to manually add fos to the composer.json and select the dev-master one ( and manually add any missing file as posted in the github discussion above )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FOSUserBundle is now compatible with Symfony 4 from release 2.1.0 (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/releases/tag/v2.1.0)

You can install FOSUserBundle with simple composer command :

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
```

The documentation is not, at this moment, very clear about how to install this bundle with Symfony 4. I have write a How To [here](https://vfac.fr/blog/how-install-fosuserbundle-with-symfony-4)

Comment: Hey @Vincent. I followed your tutorial exactly and this error keeps occuring:

`A feature you activated in FOSUserBundle requires the "mailer" service to be available. Run "composer require swiftmailer-bundle" to install SwiftMailer or configure a different mailer in "config/packages/fos_user.yaml".`

any ideas? As stated, I followed your guide and have done all steps building to this problem, including installing swift mailer

Comment: Don't worry.. doubt this was the reason but I uninstalled and reinstalled swift mailer user `composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` instead of `composer require swiftmailer-bundle` and it seems to be working now :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm use FOSUserBundle in a symfony 4 project, i think they add support a time ago.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/2639